# const char* difference in custom String class

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants, stdstring

I have a generic type of `String` which has the value of my certificate `cert.pem`
I am passing it to a function with casting to `const char*` but it does not work. My Code is below that is not working

```
String sCertificate = "cert.pem";
if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,(const char*)&sCertificate, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
        {
                mPtrLogger->logMsg(CF, "", "Unable to Load Certificate file", INFO);
                abort();
        }
```

and this code works

```
if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,"cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
        {
                mPtrLogger->logMsg(CF, "", "Unable to Load Certificate file", INFO);
                abort();
        }
```

I cant seem to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Where is the declaration of this type? You're not using the `string` the standard library provides us with.

Comment: No I have overridden string and created a generic type.

Comment: then show the class that you created for `String`!

Comment: '(const char*)&sCertificate,' is plain wrong - making a class/struct a pointer to a c-string

Comment: @DieterLücking then?

Comment: @user3172056 Take the opposite conversion - use the more  generalized type as argument, or provide more than one overload

Comment: @DieterLücking `(char&)sCertificate` like this? this is not compiling

Comment: @DieterLücking I cant seem to understand :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the `String` type has an overloaded conversion operator, you can't convert by casting.  (Think of this like casting one of your complex classes to `char *`.)

Review the methods of `String` and choose one that returns a `char *`.  The `std::string` has the methods `c_str` and `data`.

Comment: No it does not have an overload for const char* and i cannot write it as well :( Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `String` have a method that returns `const char *` or `char *`?  If not, why are you using it instead of `std::string`?

Comment: Because it is being used in all over my application

Comment: What library is your `String` from, so I can look up the information and see it contains a method that returns `const char *`?

Comment: Its generic. We wrote it our self. In the back it is using `std::string`

Comment: You will need to add a method to your `String` class to return the value of `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: that is what i cannot do :(

Comment: const char * String::c_str() { return s.c_str();}